# Move Div Inside Other Hidden Div

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to move a div inside of another div.

This is how it looks now.
[image]

When you select a Donation amount the "Choose a Purchase Plan" radio field appears.
[image]

What I want to happen is to move the "Agency" dropdown field from where it is currently to below the "Choose a Purchase Plan" radio like this. That way it will remain hidden until a donation amount has been selected.
[image]

This is the code I have presently to achieve this, but it is not working.

```js
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $(".wapf-wrapper").appendTo(".wcsatt-options-wrapper");
  $(this).hide(); // Hide move button
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="label"><label for="donation-amount">Donation Amount</label></td>
        <td class="value">
          <select id="donation-amount" class="" name="attribute_donation-amount" data-attribute_name="attribute_donation-amount"><br>
            <option value="">Choose an option</option>
            <option value="$50" class="attached enabled">$50</option>
            <option value="$100" class="attached enabled">$100</option>
            <option value="$200" class="attached enabled">$200</option>
            <option value="Custom Amount" class="attached enabled">Custom Amount</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>


    <div class="wapf-wrapper">
      <div class="wapf-field-group" data-group="74">

        <div class="wapf-field-row">
          <div class="wapf-field-container wapf-field-select" style="width:100%;" for="5f87355d578fd">

            <div class="wapf-field-label wapf--above"><label><span>Agency</span></label></div>
            <div class="wapf-field-input">


              <select name="wapf[field_5f87355d578fd]" class="wapf-input" data-is-required="" data-field-id="5f87355d578fd">
                <option value="">Choose an option</option>
                <option value="mwh9o">Lifebridge - Salem</option>
                <option value="hrv77">Plummer Youth Promise - Salem</option>
                <option value="77l7n">NSCDC Harborlight Crossing - Salem </option>
                <option value="dftor">NE Arc </option>
                <option value="7za56">Beverly Bootstraps - Beverly</option>
                <option value="jogvz">Citizens Inn</option>
              </select>
            </div>



          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <span>Choose a purchase plan:</span>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="convert_to_sub_36" data-custom_data="[]" value="0">
                    </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="convert_to_sub_36" value="1_month">
                    </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>


  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

You can see the current fields here where I am trying to achieve this: https://rootmeals.wpengine.com/product/meals-donation/

Comment: As I said in your other post.  The `wapf-wrapper` doesn't appear on `ready` but rather `ajaxComplete`

Comment: Sure thing. Give me a moment.

Comment: Okay just added the code for the form.

Comment: @HowardE I changed ready to ajaxComplete and that didn't seem to change anything.